# How to cache traffic with littleproxy/netty?

Tags: java, http, caching, networking, netty

I want to cache static files with littleproxy. So I created HashMap with key for uri and values for response body. Here's java code:

```
private static Map<String, FullHttpResponse> cache = new HashMap<>();

private static HttpFiltersSource getHttpFiltersSource() {
    return new HttpFiltersSourceAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getMaximumResponseBufferSizeInBytes() {
                return 10 * 1024 * 1024;
            }

        public HttpFilters filterRequest(HttpRequest originalRequest, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
            return new HttpFiltersAdapter(originalRequest) {
                @Override
                public HttpResponse clientToProxyRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {

                    if (httpObject instanceof HttpRequest) {
                        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) httpObject;
                        String requestUri = request.getUri();

                        if(requestUri.matches(".*[./]png.*$") ||
                                requestUri.matches(".*[./]jpg.*$") ||
                                requestUri.matches(".*[./]jpeg.*$") ||
                                requestUri.matches(".*[./]woff2.*$") ||
                                requestUri.matches(".*[./]js.*$") ) {
                            if (cache.containsKey(requestUri)) {
                                System.out.println("GOT FROM CACHE " + requestUri);

                                return cache.get(requestUri);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public HttpObject serverToProxyResponse(HttpObject httpObject) {
                    if (httpObject instanceof FullHttpResponse) {
                        FullHttpResponse response = (FullHttpResponse) httpObject;
                        String requestUri = originalRequest.getUri();

                            if(requestUri.matches(".*[./]png.*$") ||
                                    requestUri.matches(".*[./]jpg.*$") ||
                                    requestUri.matches(".*[./]jpeg.*$") ||
                                    requestUri.matches(".*[./]woff2.*$") ||
                                    requestUri.matches(".*[./]js.*$") ) {
                                cache.put(requestUri, response.retain());
                                System.out.println("ADDED TO CACHE " + requestUri);
                            }
                    }

                    return httpObject;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

But something wrong here with response in Map. When the browser reaches static files firstly there's a debug message in console: ADDED TO CACHE. When the browser reaches static files secondly there's a message: "GOT FROM CACHE", but browser spins forever waiting for a response.

What's the right way to save and store responses from server and return it to client when time comes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to also duplicate the `FullHttpResponse` to ensure you have correct writer / reader indices.

`cache.put(requestUri, response.duplicate().retain());`

and:

`return cache.get(requestUri).duplicate();`

Also ensure that you call `release()` once you remove something from the cache.